# Is pasting code from the reference source from Microsoft legal?

Tags: discussion, questions, code, legal

When using .peek and [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) in Visual Studio (15) you can check the implementation of framework types. It will download a reference source debug file, and you can check the reference-only code.

Here's an example of a post with reference source; it's a whole file copy pasted in the end:

[Example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436847/what-does-0-on-string-format-do)

I have no idea about the legal situation, and I want to know how it is.

Is it legal to post such code on Stack Overflow if I mention where it's from and keep the copyright notices in?

Comment: If this is keeping you up at night, you should ask a lawyer. SO won't give you legal advice and the folks who can answer here are for the most part not lawyers. If someone does answer you, you should not trust them unless they can cite cases that show how the court has decided in similar cases in the past. Figuring how the four factors of fair use would weigh in a *specific case* is trickier than what most think.

Comment: The US have a thing called [fair use.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) It seems likely this would be covered by it.

Comment: It is interesting that you posted the code, *then* asked if it was legal ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I posted it yesterday. I just wanted to have more clarity. I'm from switzerland, and the chance of being sued by swiss right is really low compared to american rights. I also wanted to know if it is against SO rules because everything is CC...

Comment: swiss law, not swiss right - german brain fuzzle sorry :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is *it depends*. Depends on which source you're talking about. If you're talking about the [complete framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), that's distributed with the [Microsoft Reference Source License (MS-RSL)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html), which allows using the source as a reference, but confers no additional rights. Quoting from the reference source on a site like Stack Overflow most likely falls under the banner of fair use, and is probably ok, provided that there are appropriate attributions.

Other projects have different licenses, and the only way to know for sure is to check on the [.NET Foundation Website](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/).

Here's a brief sampling of some other .NET projects with their associated license:

- [Roslyn - Apache License 2.0](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/dotnet-compiler-platform)
- [.NET Micro Framework - Apache License 2.0](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/dotnet-micro-framework)
- [.NET Core - MIT](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/netcore)
- [Entity Framework - Apache 2.0](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/entity-framework)
- [Managed Extensibility Framework - Microsoft Public License](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/mef)
- [MSBuild - MIT](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/msbuild)
- [WCF - MIT](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/wcf)

*DISCLAIMER: I am not a lawyer. If you want concrete legal analysis of the rights granted by any of the licenses discussed here, you should contact a lawyer with some knowledge of intellectual property in your jurisdiction. Nothing that I say above should be taken as legal advice.*

Comment: I think you should put the disclaimer at the beginning of your post.

Comment: theB - what about SO itself? Is it against guidelines uploading code that can't be CC?

Answer (score 1):

IANAL, however I believe you can post anything already visible with proper attribution.

That said, I *do not* see proper attribution in your post to referencesource. There is no link.

When attributing material to online source you must include the link to that material. If you were to also abide by the Chicago Manual of Style you would also add the time you accessed it and the official author of the material (Microsoft).

tl;dr; "*Full class from the reference source:*" is not enough citation. There must be a link to the cited reference.